# Refactor Duplicate Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

So we've got two methods shown below:

**Method 1**

```
private IEnumerable<object> CreateCentreViewModelForExport(IQueryable<CentreTranslation> centreTranslation)
{
    return centreTranslation.Select(s => new
    {
        id = s.Centre.id,
        centreTranslationId = s.id,
        name = s.Centre.name,
        number = s.Centre.number,
        date_opened = s.Centre.date_opened,
        address_line_1 = s.address_line_1,
        address_line_2 = s.address_line_2,
        address_line_3 = s.address_line_3,
        city = s.city,
        county = s.county,
        country = s.Centre.Country.name,
        //country_id = s.Centre.country_id,
        translatedCountry = s.country,
        postcode = s.postcode,
        hidden = !(s.Centre.CentreStatus.Where(w => w.environment_id == 4).FirstOrDefault().active),
        about = s.about,
        virtualTour = s.Centre.virtual_tour,
        directions = s.directions,
        phone = s.Centre.phone,
        fax = s.Centre.fax,
        email = s.Centre.email,
        lat = s.Centre.position.Latitude,
        lng = s.Centre.position.Longitude,
        imageCount = s.Centre.image_count,
        translatedCentreName = s.name,
        amenities = s.amenities ,
        features = s.FeatureTranslations.Select(s2 => new FeatureViewModel()
        {
            id = s2.id,
            name = s2.Feature.name,
            selected = s2.selected
        }),
        businessCentreAbout = s.ProductTranslations.Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.BusinessCentre).FirstOrDefault().about,
        officeSpaceAbout = s.ProductTranslations.Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.OfficeSpace).FirstOrDefault().about,
        virtualOfficeAbout = s.ProductTranslations.Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.VirtualOffice).FirstOrDefault().about,
        meetingRoomsAbout = s.ProductTranslations.Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.MeetingRooms).FirstOrDefault().about,
        businessLoungeAbout = s.ProductTranslations.Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.BusinessLounge).FirstOrDefault().about,
        dayOfficeAbout = s.ProductTranslations.Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.DayOffice).FirstOrDefault().about,
        language_group = s.Language.language_group,
        culture = s.Language.cuture
    });
}
```

**Method 2**

```
private IQueryable<CentreViewModel> CreateCentreViewModel(IQueryable<CentreTranslation> centreTranslation)
{
    return centreTranslation.Select(s => new CentreViewModel()
    {
        id = s.Centre.id,
        centreTranslationId = s.id,
        name = s.Centre.name,
        number = s.Centre.number,
        date_opened = s.Centre.date_opened,
        address_line_1 = s.address_line_1,
        address_line_2 = s.address_line_2,
        address_line_3 = s.address_line_3,
        city = s.city,
        county = s.county,
        //country = s.Centre.Country.name,
        country_id = s.Centre.country_id,
        translatedCountry = s.country,
        postcode = s.postcode,
        hidden = !(s.Centre.CentreStatus.Where(w => w.environment_id == 4).FirstOrDefault().active),
        about = s.about,
        virtualTour = s.Centre.virtual_tour,
        directions = s.directions,
        phone = s.Centre.phone,
        fax = s.Centre.fax,
        email = s.Centre.email,
        lat = s.Centre.position.Latitude,
        lng = s.Centre.position.Longitude,
        imageCount = s.Centre.image_count,
        translatedCentreName = s.name,
        amenities = s.amenities,
        features = s.FeatureTranslations.Select(s2 => new FeatureViewModel()
        {
            id = s2.id,
            name = s2.Feature.name,
            selected = s2.selected
        }),
        businessCentreAbout = s.ProductTranslations.Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.BusinessCentre).FirstOrDefault().about,
        officeSpaceAbout = s.ProductTranslations.Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.OfficeSpace).FirstOrDefault().about,
        virtualOfficeAbout = s.ProductTranslations.Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.VirtualOffice).FirstOrDefault().about,
        meetingRoomsAbout = s.ProductTranslations.Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.MeetingRooms).FirstOrDefault().about,
        businessLoungeAbout = s.ProductTranslations.Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.BusinessLounge).FirstOrDefault().about,
        dayOfficeAbout = s.ProductTranslations.Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.DayOffice).FirstOrDefault().about
    });
}
```

As can be seen there is a lot of duplicate code.  The second method returns a strongly typed view model, while the first returns an object due to the inclusion of two extra properties (language_group and culture).

The second method is used to populate an MVC view, the second for an export to Excel function.
What's the best way of re factoring this to minimize the duplication?

Comment: always use `CentreViewModel` and leave `language` and `culture` null if they are not needed?

Comment: Better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: From the half of the answers, it looks like I should be ditching the <object>

Comment: In general, anonymous classes should not leave the method they are defined in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a static `FromCentreTranslation` method in the CentreViewModel class, and put all initialization there:

```
public class CentreViewModel 
{
   ....
   public static CentreViewModel FromCentreTranslation(CentreTranslation source)
   {
      CentreViewModel result = new CentreViewModel();
      result.id = source.Centre.id,
      result.centreTranslationId = source.id,
      result.name = source.Centre.name,
      ....
      result.businessLoungeAbout = source.ProductTranslations
                        .Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.BusinessLounge)
                        .FirstOrDefault().about,
      result.dayOfficeAbout = source.ProductTranslations
                        .Where(w => w.Product.id == (int)Products.DayOffice)
                        .FirstOrDefault().about
      return result;
   }
}
```

You can then refactor the original two methods like:

```
private IEnumerable<object> CreateCentreViewModelForExport
                                (IQueryable<CentreTranslation> centreTranslation)
{
   return centreTranslation.Select(s => new 
   {
      centreViewModel = CentreViewModel.FromCentreTranslation(s),
      language_group = s.Language.language_group,
      culture = s.Language.cuture
   }
}
```

and

```
private IQueryable<CentreViewModel> CreateCentreViewModel
                                (IQueryable<CentreTranslation> centreTranslation)
{
  return centreTranslation.Select(s => CentreViewModel.FromCentreTranslation(s)),
}
```

Comment: Seems fairly elegant, is it appropriate to put that kind of functionality in the ViewModel?

Comment: That's your call. You could also put it in the `CentreTranslation` class and call it `ToCentreViewModel`, or in another mapper class.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a DTO class and have a setter method on it that takes in a IQueryable centreTranslation. You then pass the object to the class and set all those values in that class and pass the dto back to the original method you have there.

```
    public class SomeDto
    {
        //All of the properties your setting in the other method

        public void SetDto(IQueryable<CentreTranslation> centreTranslation)
        {
            //call methods that set all the properties
        }

        private SetAddress(IQueryable<CentreTranslation> centreTranslation)
        {
            //set only address properties
        }
```

I would also make smaller setter methods for the types like everything that has to do with an address make a private method on the dto object called SetAddress and go down the line.

After you have your DTO object you can use a tool like Automapper to map directly from your DTO object to a ViewModel object. This would give you maximum flexability for more refactoring throughout the app.

```
 private ViewModel createViewModel(Dto)

 {
     return Mapper.Map(Dto, ViewModel);    
 }
```

Comment: I do like Automapper, but I can't fully envision what you're saying here :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private IQueryable<object> CreateCentreViewModel(IQueryable<CentreTranslation> centreTranslation)
{
    return centreTranslation.Select(s => new 
    {
        model = new CentreViewModel()
        {
             id = s.Centre.id,
             centreTranslationId = s.id,
             name = s.Centre.name,
             [...]
        }
        language_group = s.Language.language_group,
        culture = s.Language.cuture
     }
}
```